# Functional way to reduce object into a string

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a good **functional** way to convert this object:

```
var globals = {
    foo: "bar",
    foo2: "bar2"
};
```

...into this string:

```
'window.foo = "bar"; window.foo2 = "bar2";'
```

Something almost similar to `Array.prototype.reduce()`.
Use of libs like Lodash is okay.

What I'm **not** looking for are **non-functional** approaches like:

```
var string = "";

// Pseudo code
_.forOwn(...) {
    string += key
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you just want someone to write code for you?

Comment: not exactly what you are looking for but handy one liner JSON.stringify(globals)

Comment: @kraftwer1 are you looking for it to work for any complicated object (object with array and it having objects etc etc ) or just simple key value ?

Comment: @AnilNamde Just simple key value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map and join

```js
var globals = {
  foo: "bar",
  foo2: "bar2"
};

var result = Object.keys(globals).map(function(key) {
  return 'window.' + key + ' = "' + this[key] + '";';
}, globals).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great, I'm wondering if there's a way without having to access `globals` within the mapper function?

Comment: @kraftwer1, you can pass it in as the `thisArg` like in my updated answer

Comment: See the second parameter mention in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I think it should be like this: `.map(function(key){...}, globals);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your Object into JSON Object then you can easily convert your JSON object into String .using JSON.Stringify()

Comment: no such thing as a JSON object, so just JSON.stringify would do

Comment: Yup, i mean in terms of object format which he have.

Answer (score 0):

[Ammar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970750/3813210) does the job in a suitably functional style, but if you just want to save the object's data as variables on the global scope, wouldn't it be easier to use a for loop, rather than eval-ing a generated string (and if you need to send or store the string, that's what JSON.stringify is for)? Like so:

```
var globalScope = (window || this);
for (var key in globals) {
    globalScope[key] = globals[key];
}
```

Comment: Good thinking, but I'm on the server side

Comment: In that case, you could JSON.stringify the object, send it to the client like that, and then JSON.parse it client-side (which is precisely what JSON is intended for). And that gives you the object you can use in the for-loop on the client. That seems easiest to me, rather than creating your own code string and relying on `eval`.

Comment: Or since you mentioned lodash, you can use the extend function (which is also in underscore.js) instead of the for loop: `_.extend(window, JSON.parse(stringifiedGlobals));`